# How to use the new Biztalk SFTP Adapter from an orchestration through a Dynamic Send Port?

Tags: biztalk, sftp

With the new Biztalk 2013, I would like to integrate the new SFTP adapter into one of my orchestration.  I did this previously with the BLogical Codeplex component.

```
MsgOut(Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.Schemas.host) = "server";
MsgOut(Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.Schemas.portno) = 22;
MsgOut(Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.Schemas.user) = "user";
```

How can I do this with the new Biztalk SFTP Adapter?

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation is here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/sftp-adapter
Unfortunately it doesn't go into details about the using it as a dynamic send port.

It does follow the patterns of the other adapters, so you need to have

```
// Set base properties 
MySendPort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = "sftp://Server[:Port]/FolderPath/";
MySendPort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "SFTP"; 

// Set the SFTP adapter specific properties 
MsgOut(SFTP.Username) = "user";
...etc
```

The properties available are those listed here [How to Configure an SFTP Send Port](https://web.archive.org/web/20141116094533/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj735584(v=bts.80).aspx) or for BizTalk 2016 and up [SFTP Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/sftp-adapter)

**except for** Server, FolderPath & Port (as you set those in the address) and ConnectionLimit.

You might also need to look at configuring the handlers for your send Dynamic Send port  [Dynamic Send Port Handler is Configurable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/dynamic-send-port-handler-is-configurable)

Also worth noting is that this SFTP adapter does not currently support connections through a proxy.  [social.msdn.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d773d51d-224b-4f5d-b130-7adf209a85cb/biztalk-sftp-adapter)